# Replacing new lines with comma, but I need file on a line

Tags: bash, file, sed, command, tr

I have 9 different files, I'm looping over each, and taking the first, second and third line.

This is my code:

```
    if [ -f displayStudentsInfo.txt ];
    then
    rm displayStudentsInfo.txt
    fi

    for f in 20*.txt
    do
    sed -n '1p' "$f" | cut -d' ' -f3 > anyfile.txt
    sed -n '2p' "$f" | cut -d' ' -f2 >> anyfile.txt
    sed -n '3p' "$f" | cut -d' ' -f2- >> anyfile.txt
    sed -E '$!s/\r?$/, /' anyfile.txt | tr -d \\r\\n >> displayStudentsInfo.txt
    done
    cat displayStudentsInfo.txt
    rm anyfile.txt
```

I have used this command to add each file on a line, but unfortunately, all the files are being added on the same line.

```
sed -E '$!s/\r?$/, /' anyfile.txt | tr -d \\r\\n
```

Output:

```
201664003, 2.8, Mathematics201700128, 3.2, Pharmacy201703451, 2.2, Political Science201759284, 3.4, Marketing201800082, 3.3, Information Technology Management201800461, 2.7, Information Technology Management201800571, 2.7, Information Technology Management201804959, 3.4, Computer Science201806050, 3.5, Computer Science201806715, 3, Computer Science201942365, 3.6, Computer Science
```

Comment: `od -c display.txt` would be a bit more straightforward

Comment: @markp-fuso I asked for this output since it can easily be reversed using `printf $(tr -d \\n | sed 's/ /\\x/')`. `od -c` is easier to inspect, but a pain to turn into an actual file you can test your commands against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea using `awk` and `printf` (sans a '\n' so all output is appended to single line):

```
awk '
     { printf "%s%s", pfx, $0        # print prefix and current line; prefix initially = ""
       pfx=", "                      # set prefix to ", " for subsequent lines
     }
END  { printf "\m" }                 # add a linefeed at the end
' display.txt
```

This generates:

```
201664003, GPA: 3.6, Major: Computer Science
```

**NOTE**: This may not work if, as indicated in other comments, there are some undesirable non-printing characters in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have Windows line endings (CR LF) instead of Linux line endings (just LF).

The whole file is still printed, but because of the CR the console overwrites already printed letters. You can confirm this by looking at the hexdump `tr '\n' ', ' < display.txt | hexdump -c`.

To fix this, remove the CRs. Also, `tr` can only replace single letters. To replace a single letter `\n` with two letters `,`  insert those two letters using `sed`.
With `sed` you can also make sure, that `,`  is only inserted between the lines, but not at the end.

```
sed -E '$!s/\r?$/, /' display.txt | tr -d \\r\\n; echo
```

The `tr` also deletes the `\n` at the end of the file. This breaks the convention that every output/file should end with a linebreak. Therefore, we add that linebreak again by executing `echo` afterwards.

`sed` command explained:

- `$!` for every line except the last one
- `s/.../.../` replace

  - `\r?` an optional CR
  - and the empty string before the end of the line (`\n`)
  - with `,`

Comment: I tried it and it's giving me the same unexpected output
sed '$!s/\r?$/, /' display.txt | tr -d \\n
Major: Computer Science

I tried adding it to a file and it's showing that it's on one line.
Why isn't it showing when we want to print it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be if this didn't work for you. Please add the output of `od -v -t x1 -An display.txt` to your question by **edit**ing so that we can try to reproduce your problem. Do **not** post that as a comment.

Comment: I added what you asked for, please check it out

Comment: @ClarkRouhana Thank you for adding the hexdump. I added the `-E` option to `sed` and now get your expected output on your file.

Comment: I edited my question, can you check it, please.

Comment: @ClarkRouhana Fixed it by adding `echo` at the end.